# How to use external datasource in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in which I've embedded a `UITableView`. If added an outlet to my ViewController class.

Because I don't want the `ViewController` to get too heavy, I would like to put the methods of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and `UITableViewDelegate` protocol into separate classes.

So I created a TableViewDataSource.swift and a TableViewDelegate class:

```
class TableViewDelegate : NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {
    //custom code here if required
}

class TableViewDataSource : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

       return 1
    }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "MyCellIdentifier"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "left text"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "right text"

        return cell


    }


}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = TableViewDataSource()
        tableView.delegate = TableViewDelegate()

        tableView.setNeedsDisplay()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

In my Storyboard, I've created a prototype cell within the tableView with the identifier "MyCellIdentifier". I use this identifier to create a cell in my TableViewDataSource method.

However, if I run the app, I only see an empty tableView. The methods don't even get called even though I have set them in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController. I also tried to enforce the tableView to redraw by calling setNeedsDisplay. This had no effect, too.

[image]

Comment: you're not really loading the tables

Comment: @lzl Can you tell me what to do in order to load the tables?

Comment: you need like an actual data source, like an array, then use the content of that

Comment: OP is just sending test data right now, @lzl. Clearly using real data is required for the final program, but right now just returning dummy data is enough to see that there's a problem.

Comment: @TwoStraws, you're right, sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, and I believe your problem is easy to resolve. See here:

```
tableView.dataSource = TableViewDataSource()
tableView.delegate = TableViewDelegate()
```

That creates a new `TableViewDataSource` and a new `TableViewDelegate` and assigns them to `dataSource` and `delegate` respectively. Here are those properties on `UITableView`:

```
weak public var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource?
weak public var delegate: UITableViewDelegate?
```

Notice the `weak` bit? You're creating them and assigning them to a weak property, so they'll get tossed away pretty quickly.

Your solution is to create properties for those two new objects inside your view controller, then create those properties in `viewDidLoad()` and send those into the table view.

Comment: Ok, now I see something. But there's something else. The text of the rightDetailLabel is empty even though I set it. The interesting thing is that the label actually exists and the text is set properly but that it is somehow not visible.

Comment: I'm glad the problem is resolved! Please mark it as correct so others can find it too. You should really post new questions as new questions otherwise others can't find them very easily. (But before you do, a brief tip: did you check your Auto Layout constraints to make sure both edges of the table are visible?)